# Action of Weyl group on $GL_n$

Tags: symmetric-groups, group-actions, algebraic-groups, weyl-group

Let $K$ be a field with $\operatorname{char}(K)=0$ and $G=\operatorname{GL}_n$ defined over $K$. The Weyl group $W$ of $G$ is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_n$. I'm now wondering if $W$ acts naturally from left on $G$ by permuting rows or columns?

Comment: Seems to depend on the choosen isomorphism from $N_G(T)/T$ to $S_n$.

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible embeddings of the Weyl group into $G$, because it is just a complement to $T$ in $N_G(T)$. A 'canonical'${}^1$ embedding is to send $\sigma\in S_n$ to the permutation matrix corresponding to $\sigma$. Whether it permutes rows or columns therefore depends on whether your action of $\mathrm{GL}_n(K)$ on the vector space is a left or a right action.

---

${}^1$ It's a good question as to whether it's possible to have *a* canonical anything, by definition of 'canonical'. Perhaps it's better to say 'natural' here.

Comment: I almost feel like it would be better to say 'a conventional' or 'an obvious' embedding, since I don't think it's natural in the category-theoretic sense (though it is *the* natural choice in a moral sense)

Comment: It's certainly geometrically natural, in its action on the root groups. I'm not sure about categorical though.